# Autowire of Spring Boot's application.properties is throwing a NPE when deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm building a spring boot application and this is my directory structure:

```
src
 main
  java
    com.company.appp
 resources
  application.properties
  log4j2.xml
```

The properties in the application.properties are getting read fine with the following autowire code:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  this.env.getProperty("test");
}
```

It is loaded in the same way in other classes too. This works fine when I run the application like this:

`mvn spring:boot run` or from IntelliJ directly with no issues. However I tried to package the WAR using `mvn clean install` which results in the following contents:

```
war
  WEB-INF
    lib
    classses
      com
      log4j2.xml
      application.properties
  org
  META-INF
```

and deployed it in Tomcat. After visiting the application URL I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `env.getProperty`.

Why is this happening when I deploy it in tomcat? How can I load the properties when deploying a spring boot war in tomcat?

Comment: Have you excluded the dependency of the embedded web container in your pom file?

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @NEO please post code that at least compiles!! Your `MyApplication` class doesn't even compile. You need to show us the pom dependencies. 
2. Try to bind the properties using `@Value("${propertyname}")`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to package that as war , any specific reason? 
Spring boot can be deployed as jar file , please refer the spring reference guide.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-packaging-for-production

src 
   main
   java --java classes.

resources
      application.properties